# How to include nodejs modules in sub directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda-layers

I have a directory structure like this for an AWS Lambda layer.

```
main > nodejs > node_modules
```

I have a `test.js` file to test functionality before uploading to AWS. Is it possible to have my `test.js` file in the `Main` folder instead of the `nodejs` folder and still have it pick up the modules in the `nodejs` folder?

I'm asking because you compress the `nodejs` folder to upload for the AWS Lambda Layer but I don't want to include my `test.js` file in the archive.

**UPDATE:** An answer below helped my find the solution. You just enter the full path to the module in require.

```
require('./nodejs/node_modules/my_module');
```

Comment: What is the tool or command you use to archive the `nodejs` folder?

Comment: I'm just compressing it from Finder on Mac and moving out the test.js file before I do.

Comment: Use tar command to zip the folder - `tar --exclude='./nodejs/test.js' -zcvf nodejs_layer.zip ./nodejs`

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip. I didn't know I could do it like that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `NODE_PATH` environment variable when you are running test.js

`NODE_PATH='yourFolder'/node_modules`

[source](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

Comment: Thank you for the link! It helped me find the solution. I didn't realize it was as easy as just entering the full path to the module like this `require('./nodejs/node_modules/my_module')`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to load the script and execute it using the [`--eval`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) flag:

```sh
cd nodejs
node --eval "$(cat ../test.js)"
```